# Multiple API Endpoints (wp_remote_get)

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to create a custom page with data from external API. But i need to get data on 2 endpoints

```
$json = json_encode(array(
));

$response = wp_remote_get('https://api1.endpoint.com', array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'X-Api-Token' => 'tokenid',
            'X-Api-Email' => 'tokenemail',
        ),
        'body' => $json,
    ));

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        if ( 200 == wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) ) {
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
            //$headers = wp_remote_retrieve_headers( $response );
        } else {
            //$error_message = wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $response );
        }
    } else {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    }
```

i need to get another data on 2nd endpoint 'https://api2.endpoint.com' which is an array. How would you suggest on combining both?

Comment: Are both calls identical more or less? and If the first fails do both fail?

Comment: the 2nd endpoint is an array - so i guess no. they are on the same server if the first one fail the 2nd will fail too. I need to display both endpoint data without having to write the whole code block for the 2nd endpoint

Comment: What does the body of the first call look like? Are you just trying to merge two arrays?

Comment: the first json looks like this
[code]
Root
  id         0
  email   a@s.com
  name  Dummy
[/code]

The 2nd is
[code]
Root
   Index 0
     long   xx.xxxxxx
     lat      xx.xxxxxx
  Index 1
     long   xx.xxxxxx
     lat      xx.xxxxxx
[/code]
so as you can see it is different, i need to loop the data of 2nd Json response on the same page.

Comment: It's pretty hard to see the code in a comment. If you can, please revise your question to include the data which will be helpful to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function to pull both the responses. Then merge the results based on a successful result.

This assumes the result for both calls is json data and should be converted to an array. I'm also using the same function calls you supplied so adjust the second where needed.

```
function get_json_data_from_2apis($api1_data = array(), $api2_data = array()) 
{
    // prepare request data
    $api1_json = json_encode($api1_data);
    $api2_json = json_encode($api2_data);

    // prep the results
    $result = array();

    // FIRST CALL

    $response = wp_remote_get('https://api1.endpoint.com', array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'X-Api-Token'  => 'tokenid',
            'X-Api-Email'  => 'tokenemail',
        ),
        'body'    => $api1_json,
    ));

    if( ! is_wp_error($response)) {
        if(200 == wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response)) {
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

            // store the first answer --- convert body to array
            $result [ 'api1' ] = array('success' => true, 'data' => json_decode($body, true));
        }
        else {
            $result [ 'api1' ] = array('success' => false);
        }
    }
    else {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        $result [ 'api1' ] = array('success' => false, 'data' => $error_message);
    }

    // SECOND CALL

    $response = wp_remote_get('https://api2.endpoint.com', array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'X-Api-Token'  => 'tokenid',
            'X-Api-Email'  => 'tokenemail',
        ),
        'body'    => $api2_json,
    ));

    if( ! is_wp_error($response)) {
        if(200 == wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response)) {
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

            // store the second answer --- convert body to array
            $result [ 'api2' ] = array('success' => true, 'data' => json_decode($body, true));
        }
        else {
            $result [ 'api2' ] = array('success' => false);
        }
    }
    else {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        $result [ 'api2' ] = array('success' => false, 'data' => $error_message);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Call the function to return both results:

```
$results = get_json_data_from_2apis(array(), NULL);
```

If they are both successful, merge the responses.

```
if($results[ 'api1' ][ 'success' ] === true && $results[ 'api2' ][ 'success' ] === true) {

    // merge the results
    $final = array_merge($results[ 'api1' ][ 'data' ], $results[ 'api1' ][ 'data' ]);

    // print them out
    print_r($final);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know if there are any errors or if this works so consider that all pseudo code.